# Users and Employees table

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I am in the process of making a database application, using LightSwitch, that tracks paperwork grouped into batches. Each of these Batches has one or more Batch_Status associated with it, and each Batch_Status has an Employee associated with it.

I want to programmatically insert a Batch_Status when a Batch is created and I want it to match up the Employee.UserName with User.Name as I want the program to work with ActiveDirectory Permissions. Any ideas?

EDIT: btw I'm using LightSwitch with VB, not C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer. I'll document it so hopefully it is useful to others. I created a query and then put this code in the Batches_Inserted Sub under the ApplicationDataService:

```
       Dim myQuery = currUserQuery(Application.User.Name)
        For Each e As Employee In myQuery
        Next
```